# Attempting to Insert Link into MySql Loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops, href

```
<ul class="items">
    <li>
        <span class = "item">
        <?php
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            foreach ($row as $key=>$val)
            {
                echo "{$val} " . " <br/>";
                echo "<br /><hr /><br />";
            }
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result); ?>
        <a href="#" class="done-button">Mark as done</a>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to add this into the loop:

`href="#" class="done-button">Mark as done`

aka - a `Mark as Done` button for a To-Do List, so that it appears next to each value that's outputted. However, I can only get it at the bottom of the page.

Comment: isn't the link supposed to be unique for each value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close! All you need to do is move the link inside of your loop, like so (I'm not sure exactly where you want your button):

```
<ul class="items">
    <li>
        <span class = "item">
        <?php
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            foreach ($row as $key=>$val)
            {
                echo "{$val} " . " <br/>";
                echo "<br /><hr /><br />";
            }
            echo '<a href="#" class="done-button">Mark as done</a>';
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result); ?>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Close! Outside the `foreach`, but inside the `while` would do the trick.

Comment: @rickdenhaan - Perfect, that did it!

Comment: I lost the css formatting of my button, but I got it show up on each row, so that's prime! I'll have to tinker around to see why I lost my css formatting.

Comment: @VivekArora Take a look at the nesting of your CSS stylesheet. You've moved your `a` from being a child of an `li` to being a child of a `span` (with a class of `item`). I don't know if that matters for your done-button class, but it's the only thing that stands out for me.